# both players controlling same player, Active Ragdoll unity2D local multiplayer using input system

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, multiplayer

I am currently making a local multiplayer game with 2D active ragdolls as the players using the Input System. I can control with both the controller, keyboard, and spawn players, but they control each other, jumping and moving.

`using UnityEngine;`
`using UnityEngine.InputSystem;`
`using System.Collections;`

`public class MovementStick : MonoBehaviour`
`{`
`public GameObject leftLeg;`
`public GameObject rightLeg;`
`Rigidbody2D leftLegRB;`
`Rigidbody2D rightLegRB;`
`public Rigidbody2D rb;`

```
public Animator anim;
[SerializeField] float speed = 2f;
[SerializeField] float jumpHeight = 2f;
[SerializeField] float legWait = .5f;
private bool isOnGround;
public float positionRadius;
public LayerMask ground;
public Transform playerPos;

// Input System variables
private PlayerControls controls;
private Vector2 movementInput;

void Start()
{
    leftLegRB = leftLeg.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    rightLegRB = rightLeg.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();

    // Enable Input System
    controls = new PlayerControls();
    controls.Enable();
    controls.Newactionmap.Move.performed += ctx => movementInput = ctx.ReadValue<Vector2>();
    controls.Newactionmap.Move.canceled += ctx => movementInput = Vector2.zero;
    controls.Newactionmap.Jump.performed += Jump;
}

void Update()
{
    // Move the character using the Input System
    float moveInput = movementInput.x;
    if (moveInput != 0)
    {
        if (moveInput > 0)
        {
            anim.Play("WalkLeft");
            StartCoroutine(MoveRight(legWait));
        }
        else
        {
            anim.Play("WalkRight");
            StartCoroutine(MoveLeft(legWait));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        anim.Play("PlayerWalk");
    }

    isOnGround = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(playerPos.position, positionRadius, ground);
}

void Jump(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
{
    if (isOnGround)
    {
        leftLegRB.AddForce(Vector2.up * (jumpHeight * 1000));
        rightLegRB.AddForce(Vector2.up * (jumpHeight * 1000));
    }
}

IEnumerator MoveRight(float seconds)
{
    leftLegRB.AddForce(Vector2.right * (speed * 1000) * Time.deltaTime);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(seconds);
    rightLegRB.AddForce(Vector2.right * (speed * 1000) * Time.deltaTime);
}

IEnumerator MoveLeft(float seconds)
{
    rightLegRB.AddForce(Vector2.left * (speed * 1000) * Time.deltaTime);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(seconds);
    leftLegRB.AddForce(Vector2.left * (speed * 1000) * Time.deltaTime);
}

private void OnDisable()
{
    // Disable Input System
    controls.Newactionmap.Move.performed -= ctx => movementInput = ctx.ReadValue<Vector2>();
    controls.Newactionmap.Move.canceled -= ctx => movementInput = Vector2.zero;
    controls.Newactionmap.Jump.performed += Jump;
    controls.Disable();
}
```

}

Comment: Theres a similar question here: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56553558/multiple-controllers-using-unitys-new-input-system) Hope it helps